# Control execution flow of multiple threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I have 4 threads running, namely A, B, C, D. 
Depending on some input condition, the execution sequence is to vary. 
For ex - for Input "0", sequence would be A->C->B-D
for Input "1", sequence would be A->D->B-C

Comment: Have you put any thought into this or are you off to lunch while we solve this for you ;)

Comment: The whole point about threads is that you DON'T control the order in which they run.  From the point of view of the program, they can be considered to be simultaneous.  If one block of work is to run after another, there's no point in putting them in threads.

Comment: @Sachin See my answer for a full fledged example.

Comment: @sachin:  I intepret "A->B" to mean "A runs and completes before B", and "X->Y-Z" to mean "X runs and completes before Y and Z, and Y and Z run in parallel".

Comment: @DavidWallace:  You *do* want to control the order in which they run, to ensure that dependences of one thread on another's results are honored.  This is the point of thread A before thread B. If there is no dependency, they can run "pure parallel".  Granted, if there is only serial execution and no parallelism, it is pointless and you shouldn't have used threads.  But in more complex situations, there is intermediate ground between "pure parallel" and "pure serial";  you may want a *partial order* on thread execution.  That makes this an interesting question, interpreted right. See my answer.

Comment: @IraBaxter Where there's some kind of partial order on the execution of blocks of work, you may need threads, but that doesn't imply that each block of work has its own thread. You may end up only breaking open a second thread when you get to two blocks of work that really can (and really should) be parallel. I guess part of the problem with this question is that it uses the word "thread" where it should say "block of work, which may or may not get its own thread". That said, there's no doubt at all that yours is the best and most useful answer here - a shame that it earned a petty downvote.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you shouldn't want to control threads in such a fine detail. However, sometimes there is a need. When writing test cases for example. So I wrote a thread scheduler for exactly this purpose:

[github.com/martinanderssondotcom/java-ee-concepts/blob/master/src/test/java/com/martinandersson/javaee/utils/ThreadScheduler.java](https://github.com/martinanderssondotcom/java-ee-concepts/blob/master/src/test/java/com/martinandersson/javaee/utils/ThreadScheduler.java)

Scroll to the bottom of the file and you can see there is a [main method](https://github.com/MartinanderssonDotcom/java-ee-concepts/blob/master/src/test/java/com/martinandersson/javaee/utils/ThreadScheduler.java#L407) which illustrate the usage of this class. Has helped me a lot when writing test code for Java EE.

Answer (score 0):

You can wait for the first thread to finish then start the next one:

```
Thread A = ...;
Thread B = ...;

A.start(); // start thread A
A.join(); // wait here until thread A finishes
B.start();
B.join();
// and so on.
```

Comment: The OP wan'ts to change the sequence of execution dynamically. This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @bot It does answer the question, but only for the first sequence. Based on this answer, he will be able to do the rest of sequences.

Comment: I disgree. The OP wan'ts to decide the order at runtime and not compile time. While you point him to the right direction, you don't answer the question at all.

Answer (score 0):

A possible approach to solve this problem would be as follows :

1. Create an ArrayList of Thread class
2. Add Thread instances to this ArrayList in the order in which you want to execute them.
3. Iterate over the ArrayList and call the start method and the join method on each of the threads one after another.

The order in which the threads should be run will be controlled by the order in which you insert them into the ArrayList.

A full working example follows :

```
public class ThreadSequencer {

    private static List<Thread> threadSequence = new ArrayList<>();
    /*Create the threads. If not using Java 8, replace ThreadSequencer::printThreadName
     * with new Runnable() { public void run() { System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());} }
     */
    private static Thread threadA = new Thread(ThreadSequencer::printThreadName);
    private static Thread threadB = new Thread(ThreadSequencer::printThreadName);
    private static Thread threadC = new Thread(ThreadSequencer::printThreadName);
    private static Thread threadD = new Thread(ThreadSequencer::printThreadName);


    private static void sequenceThreads(String input) {
        threadSequence.clear();
        if("0".equals(input)) {
            threadSequence.add(threadA);
            threadSequence.add(threadB);
            threadSequence.add(threadC);
            threadSequence.add(threadD);
        } else if("1".equals(input)) {
            threadSequence.add(threadB);
            threadSequence.add(threadA);
            threadSequence.add(threadC);
            threadSequence.add(threadD);
        }
    }

    public static void runThreads(String input) {
        sequenceThreads(input);
        for(Thread thread : threadSequence) {
            thread.start();
            try {
                thread.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                //handle exceptional cases
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private static void printThreadName() {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }

    public static void main(String []args) {
        runThreads("1");
    }
}
```

You call the runThreads method with a String and the threads will run in that sequence. That being said, if you wan't to run threads in a sequence, why create threads in the first place?

Comment: I made the same mistake you did.  Unless it is a typo, we have assume that OP intended "A->C->B-D" to mean "A before C, C before B and D"... it is not purely sequential.  So your answer isn't right. I wrote a similar answer, and then deleted it.

Comment: @IraBaxter Well, I could argue that your assumption that my assumption is wrong is also wrong. Until the OP explicitly mentions something like this in his quesiton, my understanding of the question in general is correct. If you or anyone donvoted my answer because they assumed that what the OP is saying is different, your downvote is ironic. This answer should not be downvoted.

Comment: It is clear his notation very carefully leaves the ">" out of both execution sequences.  He'd have to have made two typos consistently, and if they are typos, his question is pretty uninteresting.   You should give the other person the benefit of the doubt, where there is doubt.

Comment: That's just a theory. Until the OP clarifies it, all you are doing is making an assumption yourself. I could propose a theory saying that since the OP puts a full stop at the end of the first sentence. D should not be run at all since a full stop means don't execute anything. I hope you get my point.

Comment: Nope, I don't buy your theory.  I don't see anything wrong with his full stop in terms of the question.  Hope you got my point.   I did ask OP to clarify.

Comment: And I don't buy your theory either. You don't get the right to downvote an answer just because you think the question is asking something else. If an edit is made to the question, I will edit my answer. Until then, my answer does not deserve a downvote since any normal person would think the same way as I did.

Comment: You have not addressed why his notation is consistently different at the end.

Comment: If OP clarifies in your favor, I'll upvote your answer.  In the meantime, I'm much more comfortable with my interpretation than yours, it passes the Occam's razor test for me.

Comment: Anyone can downvote whatever they please, for any reason they please, other than who posted it.  But in this case, the notation is certainly ambiguous.  And when a question is unclear like this, the correct thing to do is to ask for clarification in a comment, rather than to make an assumption and post an answer that's possibly wrong.  Seems like a perfectly justifiable downvote to me, and one that I seriously considered adding to myself.  Moreover, instructing others not to downvote you is not how things work on Stack Overflow, and the ad hominem attack is completely unjustified.

Comment: @David You are entitled to your opinion. In my opinion, the question is not ambiguous. You and anybody else has the right to downvote an answer if it is of low quality. Down voting an answer because it does not match your interpretation of the question is what I have a problem with. You can see that there is one more answer other than mine that interprets the question the same way as I did. I expect users with higher reputation to use downvote judicially. In this particular case, the downvoter himself posted an answer based on his interpretation. Such hypocritical behavior is unjustified.

Comment: If you have a problem with such a downvote, then maybe Stack Overflow isn't the right site for you.  It's well within the rules of the site.  Telling another user that he's not "normal" is not.

Comment: Are you trying to say that stackoverflow.com is not a place for users who want to defend their answers against a downvote? Are you saying that downvoting any answer is within the rules of the site but defending an answer is not? Do you expect users to spend time answering a question and happily accept a downvote? Unless stackoverflow.com is a dictatorship,  I feel that all my comments are simply defending my answer which I have a right to do. Calling it an ad hominem attack is going to far..

Comment: Trying to bully someone into removing their downvote is very much against the spirit of the site.  Telling him he doesn't have the right to downvote your answer is incorrect and untruthful.  Telling him he's not normal is definitely against the rules.  Please don't behave like this again.

Comment: I agree about the part where the use of the word 'normal'  does have a rude interpretation now that you point it out. I meant to use the word 'average'. Any 'average'  person would think the way as I did. It was meant as a compliment to the downvoter for noticing the small details that others won't. I don't agree with the rest your points.

Comment: @sachin should check your discussion and make clarifications

Answer (score -1):

This answer is based on an assumed reading of OPs notation,
that "X->Y-Z" means "thread X runs to completion before Y and Z start".

Patching Eng. Fouad's answer to match OP's circumstance:

```
Thread A = ...;
Thread B = ...;
Thread C ...
Thread D ...

if (input==0)
  {  A.start(); // start thread A
     A.join(); // wait here until thread A finishes
     C.start();
     C.join();
     B.start();
     D.start();
     B.join();
     D.join();
   }
else
  {  A.start(); 
     A.join(); 
     D.start();
     D.join();
     B.start();
     C.start();
     B.join();
     C.join();
   }
```

As a slight optimization, the A.start();A.join() pair of statements can be lifted above the conditional.

What OP appears to want to do is define dynamic partial orders over threads.  His particular example is solvable as above.  In general, a static partial order (each arm of the "if" above) can't be accomplished by the parent thread using "starts" and "joins"; the individual threads have to do the joins to ensure they get invoked in the right order.  To do a dynamic partial order, each thread will have to check the predecessors based on the condition.

Imagine input==0 causes A->B, A->C, D->C, otherwise A->D, B->D, B->C:
You need a messier solution like this (forgive my Java, I am not an expert):

```
Thread A = new Thread(workerA)...;
Thread B = new Thread(workerB)...;
Thread C = new Thread(workerC)...;
Thread D = new Thread(workerD)...;

workerA() {
   ... 
}

workerB() {
   if (input==0)
       A.join();
   ...
}

workerC() {
  if (input==0)
     { A.join(); D.join(); }
  else B.join();
...
}

workerD() {
  if (input==1)
     { A.join(); B.join(); }
  ...
}

A.start(); // start thread A
B.start();
C.start();
D.start();
if (input==0)
   { B.join(); C.join(); }
else { C.join(); D.join(); }
```

I've assumed that Java threads can see variables from the parent thread if properly scoped.  I've also assumed that you can join to a thread more than once, e.g., several calls to A.join() from various places are OK.

If you have 10-12 threads with a complex partial order, it is pretty hard to write this and get it right. There are languages in which you can express the partial orders directly to avoid having to write all that start/join goo.

Comment: @bot: That's the spirit :-}